# Upgrade PCRE version on Ubuntu with PHP5

Tags: php, ubuntu, vagrant, pcre

I have a vagrant box running with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS which is provisioned by a shell script. I´m installing PHP5 and Apache:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php5 apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt mysql-server-5.5 php5-mysql git-core
```

I want to run TYPO3 CMS 7 which requires PCRE (Perl compatible regular expressions) with version 8.30 or higher.

If I check my PCRE version, it´s 8.12:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ php -i | grep PCRE
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.12 2011-01-15
```

If I can trust the PHP.net manual, then I should already have a higher PCRE version installed. Described here: http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php

I already tried to download it manually and `make install` it, but it was not recognized by my PHP.

So my question is, how can I easily upgrade my PCRE to a higher version? Or do you recommend other PHP packages? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade Ubuntu to 14.04 ?

Comment: Yeah @hek2mgl. Upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 bumped PCRE to 8.31 2012-07-06. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hek2mgl mentioned, using a newer version of Ubuntu within the Vagrant box did the trick.